# Creating a count up timer using Javascript in VisualForce page that doesn't reset when it refreshes?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I am trying to create a timer that counts up whenever a record populates the VisualForce page using Javascript, however, whenever the page refreshes the timer resets as well. This is a problem because I have the page to refresh every 10 seconds to check for new records. How can I circumvent this issue from occurring? Here is my VF page code.

**EDIT: Before you ask, lead__c is a custom object that we have created, I am not trying to reference the standard object "lead".**

```
 <apex:page controller="LeadAlertController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false">
    <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"/>
    <style>
    td{
        border: 1px ;
        border-style: solid;
    }

    </style>
    <table align="center" style="width:100%;border:1px solid">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <h3>Number of Hot Leads</h3>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <h3>Number of Hot Leads Over 10 Minutes</h3>
            </td>
             <td align="center">
                <h3>List of Names</h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <h1>{!Leads}</h1>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <h1>{!OverLeads}</h1>
            </td>
             <td align="center">
                <apex:repeat var="lead__c" value="{!Names}">
                <br>
    <apex:outputText value="{!lead__c.Patient_Name__c}"/>

<label id="minutes">00</label>:<label id="seconds">00</label>

     <script>


var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
var totalSeconds = 0;
setInterval(setTime, 1000);

function setTime() {
  ++totalSeconds;
  secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds % 60);
  minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
}

function pad(val) {
  var valString = val + "";
  if (valString.length < 2) {
    return "0" + valString;
  } else {
    return valString;
  }
}

    </script>

    </br>

</apex:repeat>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!if(OverLeads>0,true,false)}">
        <audio src="/resource/alert" type="audio/mp3" autoPlay="true">
        </audio>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Use `apex:inputhidden` to store the count value at the controller end, so whenever page is refreshed counter does no resets. you can set value of inputhidden by getting that by id using js.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a meta-refresh, so the entire page state is getting wiped out every time. Instead, use a Visualforce-driven refresh.

```
<apex:form id="form">
    <apex:actionPoller interval="10" 
        reRender="form" 
        action="{!updateLeadData}" />
    <table align="center" ...>
       ...
    </table>
</apex:form>
```

Once you have a form you can refresh every 10 seconds, you can then maintain the state over time.

Comment: So does this mean that I encapsulate the entirety of the code within the form or just the portion that I need to refresh?

Comment: @EdwardSobotka Yes, the timer and its script would be outside the apex:form, while the area to refresh would be inside the form.